# Quarz.NET throws Unexpected end of expression

Tags: quartz.net

I'm trying to perform the following code on a console application that uses Quarz.NET, but I got the following exception.

Here's the snippet of code

```
     public Task AddSchedule(FlussoAnagraficaItem item)
    {
        if(this.scheduler == null) throw new Exception("scheduler is null, has the InitAsync method been invoked?");

        var jobItemType = this.jobCreatorFactory.CreateJobFromAnagraficaFlussiItem(item);
        // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(jobItemType)
            .WithIdentity(item.Description, "sender")
            .Build();

        // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 10 seconds
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity($"trigger_{item.Description}", "sender")
            .StartNow().WithCronSchedule(item.Timespan)
            .Build();

        // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
        return this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

Where item.Timespan is "00 16 * * 5" , what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your cron expression is invalid. Should it run on minute 16 every hour on each day in may?

Comment: no, it shoul be on 16:00 on every friday  ```https://crontab.guru/#00_16_*_*_5```

Comment: Then this is the expression you are looking for: `0 0 16 ? * FRI *`

Comment: Please use http://www.cronmaker.com/ to build the schedules, it uses the so-called Quartz format.